# CouchDB on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

I've been trying to install couchdb on Ubuntu 10.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get install couchdb
(everything looks fine - server starts)
$ couchdb
Segmentation fault
```

The server is not accessible through curl or the browser. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Would you please paste the output of this command: `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5984/` -- thanks!